# Publish the web Api in different server

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, hosting, web-hosting

I am new to WEB API,which i want to publish in Hostgator server and need the URL so i can access through my app,Is there any procedure, so i need to do before  publishing web api 2 in different windows server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your application that use Web API 2 and your API is separate project you can open **second Visual Studio instance** and build project there. You'll get localhost URL.

Another option is to use **Local IIS** and setup your own domain. In this case you must configure Local IIS and [hosts](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/).

Last option (if you have one Visual Studio solution with Web API and App projects) is to **debug every project as separate instance**. Right click on VS project name > Debug > Start new instance.

Comment: i have hostgator windows server ,i want to host my web api in my server is it possible,i have hosted it but, i am not getting proper url need help

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. What do you mean "I am not getting proper url"? If you have own dedicated windows server, you must configure web server (IIS, services, .NET Framework, firewall)... Your server has public IP address and you need to buy domain name and set your DNS records to point this IP address. I suppose if you bought a server, you know how to set it up. Do not hesistate to write me what exactly you need to achieve.

Comment: thanks,i have hostgator windows server with some@domain.com,inside hostgator windows server,i have created the folder  with name webapi,and i have add files which consist of web api publish from my VS2015,now i need to get the url to access it from my app lik (mydomain/controller/action)

Comment: As I wrote above, you must configure your web server first. I do not know hostgator provides pre-configured server. Your application code should by placed in c:\inetpub\wwwroot by default. If you place your application code to another folder, you must set up the website in IIS.

Comment: its a pre-configured server please suggest me how i can place my file in there path